# The web application at [server] cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, sharepoint

I'm getting the following error trying to create a `SPSite` object through code:

> The Web application at http://portal.denallix.com could not be found. Verify that you have typed the
>       URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to 
>       add a new request URL mapping to the intended application. at 
>       Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(SPFarm farm, Uri requestUri, Boolean contextSite, SPUserToken 
>       userToken) at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite..ctor(String requestUrl) at 
>       AspNetSharepointListDemo.Demo.btnCreate_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
>       C:\dev\AspNetSharepointListDemo\Demo.aspx.cs:line 24

It occurs on this line: `using (SPSite site = new SPSite(listURL))` where listURL is "http://portal.denallix.com".

Information on my situation:

- Running Visual Studio 2010/C#/ASP.NET WebForms, platform target "Any CPU", targeting .NET Framework 3.5, trying both Debug and Release modes, with breakpoints and without.
- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise environment with Sharepoint 2010 installed. Seems to be the server SP server is installed on, how can I verify that?
- Tried running it both as main admin account, which is an SCA on the main site collection, and the farm admin.
- The SP url used (http://portal.denallix.com) is listed in AAM settings in Sharepoint Central Admin.
- Checked that the admin account is a member of the `WSS_ADMIN_WPG` in A/D Users and Computers.
- I'm able to browse to http://portal.denallix.com in my browser.

Anything I can do here?

EDIT: Workaround for me was to use the client object model instead, [code sample here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Is there a proxy server between you and the SharePoint server and you browser is set to pick up the proxy settings through group policy?

Comment: Ben, it looks like there isn't a proxy between the Internet and my machine, is that the same thing as what you described above?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you running your console application directly from server? Otherwise, your only option is to use client object model indeed.

Comment: Running a web application on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Change the Platform Target from **Any CPU** to **x64**

Comment: From what I'm reading, Any CPU covers both 32-bit and 64-bit in this scenario. So it should be fine at Any CPU...

Comment: Nope Sharepoint 2010 is x64. You MUST set to x64 in order to compile correctly. [See this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/manuj/archive/2010/06/19/the-web-application-at-xxx-could-not-be-found-when-using-sharepoint-om-in-an-asp-net-webapplication-on-64-bit-server.aspx), and [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/20690/the-web-application-at-url-could-not-be-found).